# How to activate a custom navigation controller that is embedded in a tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to use a cocoapod that adds a zoom transition when popping a view controller off a navigation stack:  [Zoom Transitioning](https://cocoapods.org/?q=lang%3Aswift%20zoom).  This pod works great when its just a navigation controller being used with view controllers.  This issue I'm  running into is that I have a tab bar controller that is connected to a navigation controller.  That navigation controller has a segmented control on top that determines which view will be displayed, all the views are container views:

[image: Hierarchy]

To give you an idea this is how the master view controller is set up (abbreviated):

```
 //MARK: - View - Child Views are all container views, this determines which view will be displayed based on what is selected by the segmentedController



 private func setupView() {

    setupSegmentedController()
    updateView()
  }

private func updateView() {

    //The Master VC keeps a reference to all the child VCs, each child vc is only instantiated once and never lose their state even when they are not visible

    //Deciding which view to show based on enum value
    if segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex == Selection.genres.rawValue {

      //Remove Unselected View Controllers
      remove(asChildViewController: viewControllers[.inTheatres])
      remove(asChildViewController: viewControllers[.upcoming])

      //Create Selected View Controller
      viewControllers[.genres] = viewControllers[.genres] ??
        createMoviesGenresViewController()

      //Add Selected View Controller
      add(asChildViewController :viewControllers[.genres])

 }
}

//MARK: Actions
  func selectionDidChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    updateView()
  }


  // MARK: - Create Child View Controllers Programmatically - Activated when Segmented Controller pressed

  private func createMoviesUpcomingViewController() -> MoviesUpcomingViewController {
    // Load Storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    // Instantiate View Controller
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MoviesUpcomingViewController") as! MoviesUpcomingViewController
    // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
    self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

    return viewController
  }
```

As you can see by the pic, I have the 2nd navigation controller set as a custom controller (MoviesNavigationController).

```
final class MoviesNavigationController: UINavigationController {

  private let zoomNavigationControllerDelegate = ZoomNavigationControllerDelegate()

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    delegate = zoomNavigationControllerDelegate
  }
}
```

When I set this controller as the initial controller the pod works as it's supposed to. But when I have the tab bar controller set as the initial controller like in the pic there is a delegate in the "MoviesUpcomingViewController" that is never called.

```
 //Zoom
  fileprivate var selectedImageView: UIImageView?

extension MoviesUpcomingViewController: ZoomTransitionSourceDelegate {

  func transitionSourceImageView() -> UIImageView {
    return selectedImageView ?? UIImageView()
  }

  func transitionSourceImageViewFrame(forward: Bool) -> CGRect {
    guard let selectedImageView = selectedImageView else { return CGRect.zero }
    return selectedImageView.convert(selectedImageView.bounds, to: view)
  }

  func transitionSourceWillBegin() {
    selectedImageView?.isHidden = true
  }

  func transitionSourceDidEnd() {
    selectedImageView?.isHidden = false
  }

  func transitionSourceDidCancel() {
    selectedImageView?.isHidden = false
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to get this transition working properly with the current set up?